# Google searches in my apache access logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, security

I'm quite familiar with the idea that of bots are probing my server for vulnerabilities, but today when I checked my access logs, I noticed a bunch of google searches appearing in the logs. What exactly is the point of this?

```
91.188.124.225 - - [22/Dec/2013:22:15:03 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=onet.pl HTTP/1.1" 301 325 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [22/Dec/2013:22:46:02 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wp.pl HTTP/1.1" 301 323 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [22/Dec/2013:23:16:59 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wczasy HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [22/Dec/2013:23:48:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=polska+najlepsza HTTP/1.1" 301 334 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:00:19:00 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=polska+najlepsza HTTP/1.1" 301 334 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:00:50:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wczasy HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:01:21:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=google HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:01:52:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=google HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:02:23:00 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=onet.pl HTTP/1.1" 301 325 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:02:54:00 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wakacje HTTP/1.1" 301 325 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:03:25:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=ostro%C5%82%C4%99ka HTTP/1.1" 301 345 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:03:55:58 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=polska+najlepsza HTTP/1.1" 301 334 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:04:26:54 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wczasy HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:04:58:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wczasy HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:05:29:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=google HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:06:00:00 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=onet.pl HTTP/1.1" 301 325 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:06:31:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wczasy HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:07:01:59 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wp.pl HTTP/1.1" 301 323 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:07:33:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wakacje HTTP/1.1" 301 325 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:08:04:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=onet.pl HTTP/1.1" 301 325 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:08:35:00 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=ostro%C5%82%C4%99ka HTTP/1.1" 301 345 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:09:05:58 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=praca HTTP/1.1" 301 323 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:09:36:59 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=google HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:10:08:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wp.pl HTTP/1.1" 301 323 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:10:38:59 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=google HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:11:10:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=google HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:11:41:02 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=polska+najlepsza HTTP/1.1" 301 334 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:12:12:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=ostro%C5%82%C4%99ka HTTP/1.1" 301 345 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:12:43:00 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wakacje HTTP/1.1" 301 325 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:13:13:59 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=polska+najlepsza HTTP/1.1" 301 334 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:13:44:59 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=praca HTTP/1.1" 301 323 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:14:15:59 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=praca HTTP/1.1" 301 323 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:14:47:01 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=onet.pl HTTP/1.1" 301 325 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:15:18:00 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=google HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:15:48:59 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wczasy HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:16:20:00 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wp.pl HTTP/1.1" 301 323 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:16:50:56 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wakacje HTTP/1.1" 301 325 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:17:22:00 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=wczasy HTTP/1.1" 301 324 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:17:53:00 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=ostro%C5%82%C4%99ka HTTP/1.1" 301 345 "-" "-"
91.188.124.225 - - [23/Dec/2013:18:24:00 +0000] "GET http://www.google.pl/search?q=praca HTTP/1.1" 301 323 "-" "-"
```

Comment: Welcome to the Internet where people constantly bombard your server with random junk in the hopes that something interesting will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer to this question from viewing several other server fault questions that were similar in nature, then doing some googling I found this:

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse

Comment: Probably a good idea to block that IP

Answer (score 0):

That's not google. What ever is accessing your site is requesting the page called `http://www.google.pl/search?q=some-query`

Run a whois on the requesting ip and you get this:

```
inetnum:        91.188.124.0 - 91.188.125.255
netname:        KrynskiNET
descr:          Hosting Company
descr:          Krynski NET MichaÅ KryÅski
descr:          ul. SÅawinkowska 96
descr:          20-810 Lublin
```

Comment: Yea I know it's not google, but the requests are going to google trying to use my server as a proxy maybe?